# Can I integrate Apache Shiro and CAS and WS02 Identity Server

Tags: apache, cas, shiro, wso2-identity-server

I am using Apache Shiro as a security framework for my application which also need SAML for SSO integrations. And with possible Oauth in the future.

1. Do I only need buji-pac4j to cover both SAML and Oauth?
2. With buji-pac4j, do I need to write any SAML code at all or all are taken care of by buji-pac4j framework?
3. If I have the buji-pac4j and use CasServer for authentication would it be possible to integrate other Identity management server such as WS02 Identity Server (which act as a federation hub) to the CasServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) pac4j is a generic security engine and buji-pac4j is an adapter of pac4j for Shiro. For SAML and OAuth, you need the buji-pac4j library, but also the pac4j-saml and pac4j-oauth modules

2) you don't need to write code for SAML, it's just about configuration: https://github.com/pac4j/buji-pac4j-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/shiro.ini#L33

3) you can use the buji-pac4j and pac4j-cas libraries to integrate your application with your CAS server, though I'm not sure it's exactly what you want to do

I highly recommend to take a look at the demo: https://github.com/pac4j/buji-pac4j-demo

Comment: Thanks so much for the insight! With respect to the 3rd case, I wanted to integrate the application with a CAS server as pac4j provides an adapter to do this using the pac4j-cas as you alluded to in you reply. But my understanding is that CAS is not really a federated Identity providers like WSO2. Thus, I wanted to integrate with both CAS (for SSO) and wso2 (for full federated identity stack). So my question here is, is it possible to further integrate wso2 identity server into the mixture of the buji-pac4j and pac4j-cas topology?

Comment: Got it. I don't know WSO2, but it seems to support SAML2 and OpenId Connect, thus you could use pac4j-saml and the SAML2Client or pac4j-oidc and the OidcClient to integrate with this server: https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/wiki/Clients#saml-pac4j-saml-module

Comment: Thanks for that jleleu! I wonder if something like pac4j-wso2 would be considered in the future.

Comment: Sort of. We could have a Wso2SamlClient and a Wso2OidcClient in the pac4j-saml and pac4j-oidc modules